# connecting to apache server in docker container (osx and docker-machine) FROM INTERNET

Tags: iptables, mac-osx, docker, docker-machine

In short, everything works until I try to access my apache server in a docker container from the **internet**. The incoming packets reach the docker container, but the outgoing packets get dropped by the NAT interface on docker-machine.

My setup is

- typical home LAN setup with a router connected to the internet
- osx machine running docker (ie - docker-machine aka boot2docker)
- a docker container running apache (exposing port 80 as 11111)
- I have apache running on osx (my host machine) as well which will serve as a troubleshooting tool.
- I added a bridged interface to docker-machine which connects docker-machine directly to my LAN and it gets a IP from my router.
- on my router (192.168.1.1) I've port forwarded 11111 to my docker-machine IP (192.168.1.102)

what I can do

- I can connect to apache from my host and from another computer on my
  LAN (all 192.168.1.X) because of the bridge interface on
  docker-machine. both 192.168.1.102:11111 and using
  http://:11111
- so obviously my domain resolves it's IP properly and port forwarding on my router works fine.
- I can also easily access the web server on my host machine (osx) from the internet

what I've tried

- port forwarding on my host (osx) using pfctl
- using --net=host on my container

I've narrowed down the problem (using tcpdump and other experimentation) that when I connect to the web server in the container from a computer on my LAN the packets flow through the bridged interface (192.168.1.102) in docker-machine. When I connect from the internet the incoming packet flows through 192.168.1.102, but the return packet does not. Instead it goes through the NAT interface on docker-machine and gets dropped. I've proved this by doing "ifconfig eth0 down" on the NAT interface from inside docker-machine. Now obviously this screws up my docker-machine because I can no longer run docker commands and it kills my current ssh session. But when I did this, connectivity to the web server in the container from the internet works! So I proved that the return packet is the problem.

Now, **can I use iptables inside docker-machine to route the packet properly so that it goes out the bridged interface instead of the NAT interface?** I've tried it without success. Here is my iptables rules on docker-machine. I want to route any packets coming from my container with a source port of 11111 and route them to eth1 (the bridged interface).

```
sudo iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i docker0 -o eth1 -p tcp --syn --sport 11111 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

docker@default:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:11111 flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN ctstate NEW
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

[image]

**Am I going about this all wrong? Is there a standard way to set this up that I haven't explored?**

Comment: Can you dump your rules with this command instead: `iptables-save` . It's really more clear for me. And I'm asking because I don't see any nat rule, and for sure there are some